# Doctrine Migrations, problems using custom doctrine types

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I'm building a application using Symfony2 + Doctrine2. My application needs to store geospatial data, so I wrote the proper doctrine extensions. All is working pretty good and the app have been running in a production enviroment for a long time.

Now I have to add some new features and I need to update the database without deleting all the data. I thougth about using the DoctrineMigrationBundle but when I run:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:status
```

I got this error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                     
  Unknown database type point requested,
  Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not
  support it.
```

This is the relevant section of my config.yml:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
          point: App\EngineBundle\DoctrineExtensions\PointType
```

The custom type 'point' has been mapped, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I´m on synfony 3 with postgres and I get this error, do you know how can I solve it? I do not have types inside config.yml:  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown database type point requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL92Platform may not support it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I answer my own question, it seems the problem is DoctrineMigrations also needs a mapping for the custom type. So the config.yml should look like this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
          point: App\EngineBundle\DoctrineExtensions\PointType 
        mapping_types:
          point: point
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved me some headache :-) Unfortunately, this has problems when using multiple custom types that are mapped to the same SQL native. I have two types, enumA and enumB, which both map to ENUM(...). Doctrine seens to ignore the (DC2Type:enumA) comment. :-/