# Getting error when trying to generate a migration file

Tags: php, git, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I am currently working on a Symfony project and the code is inside a `git` repo. 
We work in a one story/one branch basis and don't push code until we get a code review.

Before asking, I want to say that a working solution (already tried locally) is to merge one of the branches into the one I am currently working but I cannot do that due to processes.

So, that being said, here is my problem:

In one branch I configured my doctrine database in this way:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        types:
            point: Phil\GeolocationBundle\ORM\PointType
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types: { point: point }
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                POINTSTR: Phil\GeolocationBundle\ORM\PointStr
                DISTANCE: Phil\GeolocationBundle\ORM\Distance

phil_geolocation:
    default:
        latitude: 40.7388655
        longitude: -73.9830327
        city: New York
```

This is working fine and if I try to generate a migration file, it is generated without any problem.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

When I try to generate a migration in this branch, I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                     
  Unknown database type point requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.
```

The weird fact is that this started to happen after I worked in the other branch and, as I said at the beginning, if I merge the working branch into the non-working one, migration files is generated OK.

I tried obvious things like cleaning symfony cache (both dev and prod environments, just in case), updating composer files (because the first configuration was added by a component I needed to use, so in my second branch it was removed), checking other config files like `config-dev.yml` and so, just to double check I wasn't missing something. I even hard deleted my cache directories.

I am running out of ideas about what can be happening, it is like if it was cacheing my config file somehow, but it should be impossible!

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470630/doctrine-migrations-problems-using-custom-doctrine-types) post, but it is not what is happening to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run `doctrine:migrations:execute —down yourmigrationnumber` before moving from one branch to another?

Your database is on a different state (from the other branch) so if you run a new migration without executing the `down()` method before it will try to create a migration file removing the old state before with that type that doesn't know how to handle it.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: I knew i was missing something stupid and wasn't a bug from GIT. It worked. Thanks!